Autocompletion for useTranslation Hook not working for different namespace
I'm using React-i18next ^15.1.0 and Typescript ^5.6.3 and trying to make the autocompletion to work. I have followed both tutorial (https://locize.com/blog/i18next-typescript/) and (https://www.i18next.com/overview/typescript).
After the simple configuration does not work by importing the translation resources in a i18next.d.ts file, I decided to try the more complex approach to use the i18next-resources-for-ts interface -i ./locales/en -o ./@types/resources.d.ts command line in order to generate an interface that covers more use cases.
Now I got the autocompletion to almost work, but I only get the default namespace autocompleted but the other namespace are not available. Not only that the autocompletion doesn't work but I now get TS error:
t("timesheet:placeholder.What are you working on")
Type '"timesheet:placeholder.What are you working on"' is not assignable to type '"common.Case" | "common.Code" | "common.Price" | "common.Qty" | "common.Select Case" | "common.Select Code" | "common.Total" | "common.Unit" | TemplateStringsArray | ("common.Case" | ... 7 more ... | TemplateStringsArray)[]'

Another strange behavior is that if I change my defaultNS to timesheet, I then only have the timesheet namespace working and not the translation one.
What am I missing in order to get all namespaces to be available as a type?
Here is my config:
i18n.ts
import i18n from "i18next";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

import TIMESHEET_DE from "@/locales/de/timesheet.json";
import TRANSLATION_DE from "@/locales/de/translation.json";
import TIMESHEET_EN from "@/locales/en/timesheet.json";
import TRANSLATION_EN from "@/locales/en/translation.json";
import TIMESHEET_FR from "@/locales/fr/timesheet.json";
import TRANSLATION_FR from "@/locales/fr/translation.json";
import TIMESHEET_IT from "@/locales/it/timesheet.json";
import TRANSLATION_IT from "@/locales/it/translation.json";

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: TRANSLATION_EN,
    timesheet: TIMESHEET_EN,
  },
  fr: {
    translation: TRANSLATION_FR,
    timesheet: TIMESHEET_FR,
  },
  it: {
    translation: TRANSLATION_IT,
    timesheet: TIMESHEET_IT,
  },
  de: {
    translation: TRANSLATION_DE,
    timesheet: TIMESHEET_DE,
  },
} as const;

const defaultNS = "translation";
const ns = ["translation", "timesheet"];

i18n
  // detect user language
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
  .init({
    returnEmptyString: false,
    debug: import.meta.env.DEV,
    fallbackLng: "en",
    lng: "en",
    defaultNS,
    ns,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    },
    resources: resources,
  });

export default i18n;
export { defaultNS, ns, resources };

i18next.d.ts
import type Resources from "./resources";

import { defaultNS, ns } from "@/i18n";

declare module "i18next" {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    resources: Resources;
    defaultNS: typeof defaultNS;
    ns: typeof ns;
  }
}

resources.d.ts
interface Resources {
  "timesheet": {
    "placeholder": {
      "What are you working on": ""
    }
  },
  "translation": {
    "common": {
      "Case": "Case",
      "Code": "Code",
      "Price": "Price",
      "Qty": "Qty",
      "Select Case": "Select Case",
      "Select Code": "Select Code",
      "Total": "Total",
      "Unit": "Unit"
    }
  }
}

export default Resources;


I will actually answer my own question as I have found the answer.
The tricky part was actually somewhere in this tutorial.
The part that solve the issue is that one :

With the new react-i18next version, when loading multiple namespaces, t function will infer and accept the keys for the first namespace. So this pattern is now accepted:
const {t} = useTranslation(['ns1', 'ns2']);

So actually we have to tell the useTranslation which namespace we want to use in order for the t to be correctly typed.
